# Technique where the outline of real actors and objects is replaced by superimposed animation?

Tags: film-techniques, animation

My question is related to the following technique:

[How do they mix real characters with animated characters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/how-do-they-mix-real-characters-with-animated-characters)

Except that instead of having a real Dick Van Dyke during all the scene, an animated Dick Van Dyke is superimposed and replaces the real one. Same with the wooden gate: a real one with lots of details and color shades is replaced by an extremely simplified gate with minimum shades and traces, while keeping the resemblance to the real thing.

I need to hire a professional animator to do something like that, but I do not even know the name of the technique.  It is often used in TV commercials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called rotoscoping. It's a technique where film is 'traced' for animation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping

Comment: Do you know what software can be used for rotoscoping?

Comment: @TravisBanger google 'rotoscoping software.' But note that it's not just a simple software filter. It typically involves a lot of hand work.

Comment: A lot of people just use Flash...